# where to configure AWS trust relationship?

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, authentication

I can't find [this setting](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33850060/262852) on the web interface for AWS:

> You also need to edit the Trust relationship for the role to allow the
>   account (even if it's the same) to assume the role.
>
> ```
> open the role that you want to assume in the console
> click on the "Trust Relationships" tab
> click on "Edit RelationShip"
> ```

Is there perhaps a screenshot?  I'm reading the [*AWS Command Line Interface User Guide*](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-roles.html#cli-role-prepare)  manual, but don't see where to configure the Trust Relationship.

```
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ cat .aws/config 
[default]
output = text
region = us-west-2



[profile thufir]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/thufir
source_profile = default

thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws iam list-users
USERS   arn:aws:iam::1234567890:user/thufir 2017-01-02T10:09:01Z    /   ABCDEFGIJKL thufir
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws s3 ls --profile thufir

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ export AWS_DEFAULT_PROFILE=thufir
thufir@doge:~$ 
thufir@doge:~$ aws s3 ls --profile thufir

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the AssumeRole operation: Roles may not be assumed by root accounts.
thufir@doge:~$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the AWS console, visit [IAM roles](https://console.aws.amazon.com/iam/home#/roles), then click on the relevant role. Once you do that, you'll see a page like this, with the Trust Relationships tab:

[image]